# JavaFX Table/TreeTable Cell Overflow

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to get the text in a treetable cell to overflow into the adjacent cells. I believe that I read a while ago that there is no Span function in tables or treetables, but it might be accomplished through css.

See this image. I want the date in the first cell to extend past the others so it can be read.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCtx2.jpg

I thought I would use *-overflow: visible;* but I read in the Oracle documentation:

> JavaFX CSS does not support CSS layout properties such as float, position, overflow, and width.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? CSS would be preferable, but would a custom TreeTableRow be the right solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [RT-22593 Labeled popover overflow display](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22593) for related feature request.

Comment: That looks similar but different (also looks like they are not getting on it anytime soon). Do you think a custom treeTableRow would work? (BTW... you the man for all your previous help in SO... greatly helped me learn javafx quickly. Thanks for your work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample Solution**

Here is an overflow cell for a TableView, you could probably adapt it for a TreeTableView.

```
class OverflowCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {
    private Label overflowLabel = new Label();
    private Group overflowGroup = new Group(overflowLabel);

    public OverflowCell() {
        // destroy the clip.
        clipProperty().addListener((observable, oldClip, newClip) -> {
            if (newClip != null) {
                setClip(null);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            overflowLabel.setText(item);
            setGraphic(
                overflowGroup
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Normally the cells in a TableView are clipped, so the listener is added in the constructor of the OverflowCell to remove any clip added to the cell.  The updateItem call uses a Group so that the Label is not resized to a size smaller than it's preferred size and elided.

There are probably other ways to do this. A custom row factory might be an alternate solution.  This OverflowCell hack was just a simple thing which came to mind.

**Sample Code**

Here is it in action, you can see how the last name in the first line overflows into the next column.

[image: overflow]

Apologies for the amount of code here.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableCellOverflow extends Application {

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Person("Jacob", "Krzyzanowski", ""),
                    new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                    new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                    new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                    new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
            );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");

        table.setPrefHeight(200);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMaxWidth(80);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        firstNameCol.getStyleClass().add("left-header");

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>();
        lastNameCol.setMaxWidth(60);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
        lastNameCol.setCellFactory(param -> new OverflowCell());

        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        emailCol.setMaxWidth(100);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    class OverflowCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {
        private Label overflowLabel = new Label();
        private Group overflowGroup = new Group(overflowLabel);

        public OverflowCell() {
            // destroy the clip.
            clipProperty().addListener((observable, oldClip, newClip) -> {
                if (newClip != null) {
                    setClip(null);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                overflowLabel.setText(item);
                setGraphic(
                        overflowGroup
                );
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, that worked great. I added "-fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;" to the CSS to hide the vertical grid lines and it looks perfect now. Thanks